# F# return empty string in case of null

Tags: f#

I'm trying to touch some F# language by developing a small "web crawler". I've got a functions declared like this:

```
let results = HtmlDocument.Load("http://joemonster.org//")

let images = 
results.Descendants ["img"]
|> Seq.map (fun x -> 
    x.TryGetAttribute("src").Value.Value(),
    x.TryGetAttribute("alt").Value.Value()
)
```

which of course should return for me a map of *"src"* and *"alt"* attributes for *"img"* tag. But when I'm encountering a situation when one of those are missing in the tag I'm getting an exception that **TryGetAttribute** is returning null. I want to change that function to return the attribute value or empty string in case of null.
I've tried out answers from [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642554/f-option-equivalent-of-cs-operator) but with no success.

Comment: Where is `TryGetAttribute` coming from? XMLLinq extension method? Your problem is that you're doing a `.Value` on it and that will look inside. First return whatever `TryGetAttribute` gives you back, than pattern match on that result to give your desired output.

Comment: TryGetAttribute is comming from FSharp.Data library, it docs can be found here: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-htmlnodeextensions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TryGetAttribute` returns an *option* type, and when it is `None` you can't get its *value*—you get an exception instead. You can pattern match against the returned option value and return an empty string for the `None` case:

```
let getAttrOrEmptyStr (elem: HtmlNode) attr =
  match elem.TryGetAttribute(attr) with
  | Some v -> v.Value()
  | None -> ""
let images = 
  results.Descendants ["img"]
  |> Seq.map (fun x -> getAttrOrEmptyStr x "src", getAttrOrEmptyStr x "alt")
```

Or a version using `defaultArg` and `Option.map`:

```
let getAttrOrEmptyStr (elem: HtmlNode) attr =
  defaultArg (elem.TryGetAttribute(attr) |> Option.map (fun a -> a.Value())) ""
```

Or another option now that `Option.defaultValue` exists, and using `HtmlAttribute.value` function for a terser `Option.map` call:

```
let getAttrOrEmptyStr (elem: HtmlNode) attr =
  elem.TryGetAttribute(attr)
  |> Option.map HtmlAttribute.value
  |> Option.defaultValue ""
```

Comment: @TaylorWood Regarding the second approach, you don't need to do this anymore. Option finally has `defaultValue`. So you can just do, `Option.defaultValue ""  (elem.TryGetAttribute(attr))`.